# When I deploy to meteor.com I'm getting - error: 500, reason: "Internal server error" but on my machine it's fine

Tags: meteor

I'm working on an app that uses an npm package (cheerio) to scrape the front page of Google News.

On my local machine, everything runs perfectly without errors. However, when I deploy to Meteor.com I'm getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r3Bg.png

My app is deployed to http://scrapethenews.meteor.com.

I don't understand why there would be an error on Meteor.com but not on my local machine.

I haven't done any pub/sub and I haven't implemented any security features.

Any ideas?

**All.js**

```
ScrapedLinks = new Mongo.Collection("scrapedLinks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.all.helpers({
        returnLinks: function() {
            return ScrapedLinks.find({}).fetch()
        }
    })

    Template.nav.events({
        'click .technology': function() {
            var url = 'http://news.google.com/news/section?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&topic=tc';
            Meteor.call('scrapeCat', url, function(error, result) {
                console.log(error)
            });
            ts = ScrapedLinks.find({}).fetch(); for (i = 0; i < (ts.length); i++) {ScrapedLinks.remove({_id: ts[i]._id})

        }
    }
    })
}
```

**Methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({

scrapeCat: function(url) {

    var cheerio = Meteor.npmRequire('cheerio');
    var request = Meteor.npmRequire('request');

    request(url, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        var i = 0;
        $('h2.esc-lead-article-title').filter(function() {

            link = $(this).children().attr('href')
            var time = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
            i = i + 1
            if (i < 21) {
                ScrapedLinks.insert({
                    link: link,
                    title: null,
                    description: null,
                    pic: null,
                    number: i
                })
            }
        })

        var f = 0
        $('h2.esc-lead-article-title').filter(function() {
            title = $(this).children().children().text()
            f = f + 1
            if (f < 21) {
                ScrapedLinks.update({number: f}, {$set: {title: title}})
            }

        })
        var d = 0
        $('.esc-lead-snippet-wrapper').filter(function() {
            description = $(this).text()
            d = d + 1
            if (d < 21) {

                ScrapedLinks.update({number: d}, {$set: {description: description}})
            }

        })
        var h = 0
        $('.esc-thumbnail-image').filter(function() {
            var picBefore = $(this).attr('src');
            var http = "http:";
            var pic = http.concat(picBefore)

            h = h + 1
            if (h < 21) {
                ScrapedLinks.update({number: h}, {$set: {pic: pic}}, console.log('done'))
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log(error)
    }}));
}
});
```

**All.html**

```
<template name="all">
    <div class="ui three column page grid">
        {{#each returnLinks}}
        <div class="column">
            <div class="ui segment">
                <div class="picBox">
                    <a href="{{link}}">{{title}}</a>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <img onerror="this.style.display='none'" src="{{pic}}" /> <br />
                    <b>{{description}}</b>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?